# Bitset not properly extracting bits

Tags: c++, bitmap, file-read

I am trying to read a bitmap from a binary file. I confirmed that the bytes are being written correctly to the binary file. I am now trying to open that binary file up, read the bytes, extract the bits from those bytes, and store them in an array. Bitset works for the first byte but fails for all proceeding bytes.

```
void loader::load_inode_map(string filename){
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb+");
    fseek(fp, sb.block_size, SEEK_SET);
    bitset<8> bit;
    char c;

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        fread(&c, 1, 1, fp);
        bit = c;
        cout << "---new byte---" << endl;
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--){
            cout << bit[j] << endl;
            inode_map[count] = bit[j];
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

To test the functionality of this function, I set all of the bits to 1. This prints out for the first byte, but all of the bytes afterword are only printing out 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
Output:
---new byte---
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
---new byte---
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
---new byte---
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...and so on.
```

Comment: So I'm pretty sure you're using c++ because of the class and string; and cout.  But then what's this fopen about?

Comment: We have no idea what's in that file you're reading.  How about skipping the file reading for the sake of this question, and just hard-code the values in some sort of an array to verify that bitset "doesn't work properly".

Comment: And what is the value of `sb.block_size`?  How far into the file are you seeking?

Comment: It looks like it should be working fine (at least the `bitset` stuff)

Comment: Why is there no output for `c` after it has been read in?  You output everything else except the most important aspect of the issue.

Comment: what is `sb.block_size` and what is the "bits per pixel" for the bitmap file? Note that high color bitmaps use bytes to store the color.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is rooted at `fread` failing.

Try checking it's return value:

`if (fread(&c, 1, 1, fp) != 1) { /* error! */ }`

You should also consider using `std::ifstream`, otherwise you are prone to leaking resources.

Here are the methods you will require:

```
std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
file.seekg(sb.block_size);
if (!file.good()) { /* error! */ }
file.read(&c, 1);
```